# Python IDLE/Terminal return back after error

Tags: python, terminal, edit, python-idle, undo

When reading a book or just coding on terminal/IDLE it's common to make typo, forgot brace or comma etc. After I got error and all what I wrote before is lost.
Then I have to write down code again..
Is there any way/option to return back all what write before and just edit mistake and continue to code?

Answer (score 0):

In Idle (at least my version, Python 2.7.10 on windows), you can simply copy paste your code. In the python interpreter, you can't afaik, however you can use the up/down arrow keys to recall lines you previously "submitted" (i.e. typed and pressed enter).

Comment: Yes, I'm doing this right now.
Mostly I write down the code that I see, without copy/paste it.
But it's annoying to resubmit every line of code after failing it.. if it's small piece of code, then it's okay. but if larger..

Comment: Terminal/interactive mode should really only be used form smaller pieces of code - for larger pieces of code you can make separate .py files. In idle, you can do this using file -> new file, or you can use basically any text editor like notepad, notepad++, or more advanced IDE's such as spyder.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, IDLE is a GUI (graphical user interface - a visual representation of a program rather just through text) made to have a bit more features for programming in Python. You can use IDLE interactively, like in Terminal (a.k.a command line), or use it to write your script rather than in a separate text editor. Then once you save your script/program you can do neat things like run it directly from IDLE. There's nothing more special about the Terminal, you just have to do some more work.

Furthermore, all the code you have written on your GUI is on the cache memory which is used in system to store information recently accessed by a processor. So, I suggest you write again your code you can't recover them without saving.
To avoid these kind of problems use **Git**!

Git is a version control system that is used for software development and other version control tasks.

Comment: For larger pieces of code (really larger) I use PyCharm and of course git, but when I read book and just follow code, it's kinda 20+ lines of code, I don't need to use PyCharm, it's easier and faster to do it in terminal. But after making typo, it annoys me to use arrow keys to resubmit all code again.

Comment: I hear you but now, you know you must save your code whenever using this kind of terminal. So this was an experience and to get experience sometimes we should pay some costs :)

Comment: Yeah, I know. Hoped maybe there's any solution to avoid it. Just it could save little bit more time in every Python developer's life.

Answer (score 0):

IDLE's Shell window is statement rather that line oriented.  One can edit any line of a statement before submitting it for execution.  After executing, one may recall any statement by either a) placing the cursor anywhere on the statement and hitting Enter, or b) using the history-next and history-prev actions.  On Windows, these are bound, by default, to Alt-p and Alt-p.  To check on your installation, Select Options => IDLE preferences on the menu.  In the dialog, select the Keys tab.  Under Custom Key Bindings, find the 'histor-xyz' actions in the alphabetical list.

For short, one-off scripts, I have a scratch file called tem.py.  Since I use it often, it is usually accessible via File => Recent files.